# Recovering Greenshot open image editor screenshots after reboot

Tags: recovery, greenshot

I know this is a longshot, but I'm wondering if there is any way to recover unsaved Greenshot image editor images.

I had about 10 images open in various image editor windows. Before I could save them, I left my desk and Windows decided that it was a good time to apply updates and restart.

I'm wondering if these images would be cached somewhere, of if they are completely lost.

I already checked AppData Local and Roaming, and all I found were config files. The program directory itself didn't have anything either.

I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: Check the Recycle Bin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not. The Greenshot editor does not save images to temporary files or similar. Sorry :-/

Answer (score 0):

Based on your post (restarting  before saving), I would not get your hopes up. Very most likely your images are gone.

Please see:

[Greenshot log file](https://getgreenshot.org/faq/where-can-i-find-greenshots-log-file/)

> In case you encounter things not working as expected in Greenshot, the
> log file might help you: it hopefully contains some information on
> what went wrong, and maybe even why. Greenshot’s log file is called
> Greenshot.log. Depending on which version of Greenshot you are using
> on which version of Windows, the log file can be found in one of the
> following directories:
>
> If you are using the installer version of Greenshot, the file is
> stored in your (local) application data folder, which is a path like
>
> C:\Users%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Greenshot\ in Windows Vista and
> newer version

Comment: Log file had nothing to do with caching images.

Comment: But also I told you your images are gone and they are.